# Swift 3: UICollectionView download video snapshot. UI is freezed while trying to download snapshot

Tags: xcode, asynchronous, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm trying to download video preview base on remote video URL. In my project, the server cannot return snapshot image of the videos, that's why I have to do it manually.
In table view, I have code like this in cellForItemAt to get video preview

```
            DataManager.sharedInstance.getCachedImage(url: movie.url!, handler: { (image) in
            cell.ivCover.image = image
        })
```

and my getCachedImage function in DataManager:

```
    func getCachedImage(url: String, handler: @escaping(_ result:UIImage) -> Void){
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        if let imageData = userDefaults.object(forKey: url){
            if let finalImg = UIImage(data: imageData as! Data){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    handler(finalImg)
                }
                print("USING CACHED IMG")
            }else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    handler(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cover"))
                }
                print("Cannot parse cached data to image. Use default")
            }
        }else{
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: url)!)
            let generate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            var thumbTime = asset.duration
            thumbTime.value = 1
            var imgRef:CGImage?
            do{
                print("Downloading thum from url: \(url)")
                imgRef = try generate.copyCGImage(at: thumbTime, actualTime: nil)
            }catch let error{
                print("Error download thum: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

            var finalImg:UIImage
            if let _ = imgRef{
                finalImg = UIImage(cgImage: imgRef!)
                userDefaults.set(UIImagePNGRepresentation(finalImg), forKey: url)
            }else{
                finalImg = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cover")
                print("Download thumnail failed. Use default")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                handler(finalImg)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that, sometimes I scroll the Collection view, UI is freezed, sometimes it's not. Please note that this video is on REMOTE SERVER, NOT local video.
I've spent days to figure out the issue but still not able to find out what went wrong. Please help!
Or is there any existing library I can use?

Comment: based on your code your downloading image from server am i right ? or you are downloading video from server ?

Comment: I'm NOT downloading the video file, I'm trying to get SNAPSHOT of the video

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ImportViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {

let videoURL = "https://youerdomin.com/file.mp4"

print("1")

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

   print("2")

    if let url = URL(string: videoURL), let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {

       print("3")

    let documentsPath = 
  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];

    let filePath="\(documentsPath)/tempFile.mp4"

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        print("4")

        urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({

            print("5")

            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))

        }) { completed, error in

            print("6")

            if completed {

                print("Video is saved!")

            }else{

                print("7: ",filePath)

            }
        }
    }
}else{

    print("8")

}
}
}
}
```

Comment: This code downloads the video from the link and saves it to the camera albums